# run sencha app build has exception,error msg is " mand.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:98)"

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

excute sencha cmd command "build app build",console tip has exception.
error msg :

```
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: Cannot find file :\src_sources\wy\src\main\newwebapp\build\temp\production\GasApp\slicer-temp\theme-capture.json
[ERR]   at com.sencha.com
[ERR] mand.BasePluginCommands$BasePluginCommand.doExecute(BasePluginCommands.java:98)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 3 minutes 16 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
```

Comment: check whether `theme-capture.json` exist

Comment: @ppz No, should theme-capture.json files be generated automatically when packaged

Answer (score 0):

***replace your WEBCONTENTS->BUILD->TEMP FILES with your colleagues and rerun sencha app build command.***